# Copy list of files to a folder - with condition

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have a folder which contains 10K+ pdf files and I want to copy few files from that folder to another folder from a filelist (ListFile.txt) which has list of files I want to copy.

Now I want to copy only when the count of files found is >=2.

If 0 or only 1 document is found for the record in the list, it shouldn't copy and generate a separate report for these.

This is what currently exists and is working fine but its pulling everything based on the ListFile.
If the count of pdf files it found in AllDocs folder is 1 or 0, it shouldn't copy and create a separate log file for them.
Currently if 1 pdf is found, its being copied to "CopyToFolder" and single log file is created for everything.

```
@echo off
set logfile=logfile.txt
call :LOG > %logfile%

:LOG
if exist "ListFile.txt" (
  for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("ListFile.txt") do (
     copy /Y "AllDocs\*%%I*" "CopyToFolder"
  )
)
```

Contents of Listfile.txt:

111

222

333

444

Example contents of Alldocs folder:

ABC_111_Record1.pdf

ABC_111_Record2.pdf

ABC_111_Record3.pdf

ABC_222_Record1.pdf

ABC_333_Record1.pdf

ABC_333_Record2.pdf

In the above example, all files for 111 and 333 should be copied since 2 or more files exists for them. Only 1 file exist for 222, so it should not be copied.

Comment: To begin with, you need one or more commands to be inserted from the first empty line. Your code currently will run through the `:LOG` label again immediately after having completed the `call` command line.

Comment: Could you please update your question to remove some confusion it creates. You stated that your `ListFile.txt` contains a "list of files". You also said that you "have a folder which contains 10K+ pdf files", (`AllDocs`). Your code shows a wildcard pattern/glob too. So, as it is not possible to have two or more same named files in a directory, are we to assume that `ListFile.txt` contains only partial filename strings, or strings including a partial directory and filename. We really need some clarity on that, and preferably a representative example of the text file content.

Comment: Updated the question with examples of ListFile.txt and AllDoc folder contents.